# Check if struct within struct exists

Tags: json, go, struct, goquery, encoding-json-go

I have a json feed, and am trying to check if a struct within a struct exists.

```
type feed struct {
    Video          struct {
        Name string      `json:"name"`
    }   
}
```

And here's the unmarshal process:

```
data:= &feed{}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(structuredData), data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

In some cases, `Video` exists and in other cases, it doesn't. I would like to validate this in an if statement, something like `if data.Video != nil` but this doesn't seem to compile (I get `invalid Operation`). How do I check whether `Video` exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a valid video has a non-empty name, then use `data.Video.Name != ""` to check for a valid video.

If you want to detect whether the video object is included in the JSON or not, then declare the type with pointer to the struct:

```
type feed struct {
    Video          *struct {  // <-- note * on this line
        Name string      `json:"name"`
    }   
}
```

The JSON decoder allocates the inner struct only if the JSON document has a video object.

Check for the presence of the video object in the JSON document using `data.Video != nil`.